# How to implement nested collapsibles?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the code for an animated collapsible on this link:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Style the button that is used to open and close the collapsible content 

*/
.collapsible {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the collapsible content. Note: hidden by default */
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

JS:

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

I want to implement another collapsible button inside the first collapsible drop down. As of right now my nested button does nothing when I click the + icon other than change to a -. Here is my html:

```
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Options:</button>
<div class="content">
    <button class="collapsible">Check</button>
    <div id="content"> 
        TEST 
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS and JS are the same as in the link.

Comment: "css js are the same". You should write a *runnable* snipper complete with your JS and CSS. The person answering your question isn't paid to answer this question nor should he need to copy/paste code you didn't include.

Comment: The code is in the link I provided though. It's not exactly much more work. I think providing the link to the source I'm using is far more helpful than a snippet of the same thing. The link at least provides context. Sometimes I feel like this sites users need to be a bit more relaxed.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your question. A link is great. Sometimes, though, the content at the link can change or move somewhere else. Providing the JavaScript and CSS in your question would indeed make it easier to copy/paste but more importantly it would help make sure that even if the link was not working, your question can stand the test of time! It will help people who might have the same question as you in the future. I would be happy to edit your question and add the code to it  but Stack Overflow does not allow this as it would change your original question too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created first loop to calculate all class `content` heights to be able to use this number as `max-height` to the main container. you can use css display `block` and `none` instead, but i do this to create animation.

```js
var allHeights = 0;
var contents = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
var j;

for (j = 0; j < contents.length; j++) {
  var h = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[j].scrollHeight;
  allHeights += h;
}

var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight == allHeights + "px"){
      content.style.maxHeight = "0px";
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = allHeights + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">First Collapsible</button>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  
  <button type="button" class="collapsible">Second Collapsible</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>

  <button type="button" class="collapsible">Third Collapsible</button>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in nested content `div` element. Instead of `id="content"` there should be `class="content"` to have it working correctly. Take a look at the snippet below.

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
/* Style the button that is used to open and close the collapsible content */
.collapsible {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the collapsible content. Note: hidden by default */
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Options:</button>
<div class="content">
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">Check</button>
    <div class="content"> 
        TEST 
    </div>
</div>
```